# Problems uploading file to Amazon S3 using Retrofit2 on Android

Tags: java, android, amazon-s3, retrofit2

I am trying to upload a file (taken by my device's camera) to Amazon S3. Unfortunately, the request fails with an InvalidArgument exception:

```
<Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message></Message><ArgumentName>x-amz-acl</ArgumentName>
```

The request should take the form of:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryPJf5u1BglONosgFh
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"

uploads/FooBar/<SOME ID>/db8218d9-2e45-4ed4-bd44-70019bbf6047_${filename}
------WebKitFormBoundaryPJf5u1BglONosgFh
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="success_action_status"

201
------WebKitFormBoundaryPJf5u1BglONosgFh
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="acl"

public-read
------WebKitFormBoundaryPJf5u1BglONosgFh
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Expires"

Wed, 11 May 2016 13:26:28 GMT
------WebKitFormBoundaryPJf5u1BglONosgFh
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryPJf5u1BglONosgFh--
```

I have the Retrofit logger enabled, however unfortunately it does not output the request body.

I do not set `x-amz-acl` in my header.

My service is as follows:

```
 public interface FileUploadService {
      @Multipart
      @POST("/")
      Call<FileUpload> upload(@PartMap LinkedHashMap<String,String> params, @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
 }
```

Inside my camera fragment, I do:

```
// Get my image
ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
buffer.get(bytes);

RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), bytes);
MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file","filename.jpg", requestFile);

// Get parameters from upload URL request
LinkedHashMap<String, String> params = response.body().getFields();


uploadService.upload(params, body).enqueue(new Callback<FileUpload>() {

         @Override
         public void onResponse(Call<FileUpload> call, Response<FileUpload> response) {
              // DO STUFF
         }

         @Override
         public void onFailure(Call<FileUpload> call, Throwable t) {
             // DO STUFF
         }
});
```

The parameters from the URL request are all correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind an alternative approach to your problem, please let me suggest the following approach.

- Download `commons-net-3.4.jar` from [apache commons website](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/download_net.html)
- After unzipping the downloaded file, add the jar file to your `libs/` folder.
- Then Right-Click -> Add as Library to your app module. Should be straightforward. You will notice it will add the library to your `build.gradle` file and ready for use.
- When you are ready, regardless of which approach you want to do the background operation of uploading the file, you can use the following sample code:

  ```
  public class SyncFileToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params){
          FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();


          try{
             ftpClient.connect("xxx.xxx.x.xxx");
             ftpClient.login("username", "password");
             ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
             ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

             File file = new File("path/to/file");

             FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

            if(ftpClient.storeFile("filetotransfer", inputStream)){
                ftpClient.disconnect();
                return "success";
            }else{
                ftpClient.disconnect();
                return "ERROR";
            }
          }catch (IOException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
      }

      return null;
  }
  ```

Since you have to get the file location from your device, you can simply pass it as a param to the async task or even a service. When the operation is completed, you can update the UI accordingly using events or something you like.

Using the `commons` library is much easier and faster in my opinion because you only need to write a few lines of code!

I hope this helps you solve your issue and good luck!

Comment: Thanks Eenvincible. However, I would prefer to resolve this without using FTP. Would you have another recommendation?